# HTML show image, then wait, then show another image

Tags: php, jquery, html, wait

what I am trying to do is make it so when the user checks off a radio box, an image shows, and after 10 seconds, an swf file shows. I have the image working. I tried using php sleep in my html function, but the sleep starts right as the page loads, keep in mind that all of this needs to be done in an onlclick function. I also tried using a javascript function to get the stuff from another php file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doit()
{

  $.get("dumplings.php");
    return false; } 



</script>
```

Dumplings.php sleeps for 10 seconds,then echoes my html with the swf in it. That did not work either.

Here is my radio box

```
<input name="sample_check3" id="sample_check3" value="1" type="radio" onclick="showStuff('img');doit();"/>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a setTimeout in javascript instead? There is no need to let a PHP-script sleep for 10 seconds to wait with delivery, it only hogs resources.

Comment: You mean settimeout before it gets the php file? THen inside the php file it echos the html? Because what it is trying to do now is get the php file, then the php file sleeps and echos it, but if it hogs recources or not, it still didnt work

Comment: can you show a small demo at jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="json.json"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sample_check3").on('click', function(){
        if($(this).attr('checked') === 'checked'){
            $("#image1").css('display','');
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#image1").css('display','none');
                $("#image2").css('display','');
            },3000);
        }
    });
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input name="sample_check3" id="sample_check3" value="1" type="radio"/>
<img id="image1" src="http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/nguesto/images/pikachu.jpg" style="display:none"/>
<img id="image2" src="http://faqsmedia.ign.com/faqs/image/ani004.gif" style="display:none"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So I would call the setTimeout() in onclick?

Comment: Yes, call it on click but make sure to check that it is 'checked' before calling setTimeout

Comment: Ok, and I dont need any params for setTimeout because it is in the function?

Comment: Exactly. The setTimeout takes a callback. In the given example the callback is the anynomous function, but could just as well be a function name.